# is there a function to swap the next row column value to current row column value in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
Row1    x1  x2  y2
Row2    y1  y2  z2
Row3    z1  z2  (next row4 column2.value)
```

I am trying to fetch a sql query where i to have print the column3 from row2.column2

Comment: If i undersoood properly, try to use LAG or LEAD Oracle build-in functions. SELECT column2, 
LAG (column2,1) OVER (ORDER BY column2) as column3
FROM your_table_name;

Comment: Thank you it works... by using "LEAD"

Answer (score 3):

I presume it is `LAG` you need:

```
SQL> with test (id, col1, col2, col3) as
  2    (select 1, 'x1', 'x2', null from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'y1', 'y2', null from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'z1', 'z2', null from dual
  5    )
  6  select id, col1, col2, lead(col2) over (order by id) col3
  7  from test
  8  order by id;

        ID COL1 COL2 COL3
---------- ---- ---- ----
         1 x1   x2   y2
         2 y1   y2   z2
         3 z1   z2

SQL>
```

I've included the `ID` column as you have to have something to order rows by. Doesn't have to be the `ID`, could have been some date value or whatever else.

Comment: Thank you got it... So, what i am doing is that i am  getting the next row value so i have to use the "LEAD" and it works. when i have to take previous row value then i have to use the "LAG"